# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key authView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

When i run my app on simulator it runs well, when i try with device doesn't work and i get these errors:

**NOTE**: i didn't find any kind of class authView in my code

```
2011-02-24 12:04:14.472 TestP[473:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TestP 0x19d2b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key authView.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x33ac0987 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3347b49d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x33ac0705 -[NSException dealloc] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x3367db4f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)    setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 182
4   Foundation                          0x3367d03b _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 90
5   Foundation                          0x3367eda3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 194
6   Foundation                          0x33630b17 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 130
7   UIKit                               0x3224c60f -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 66
8   CoreFoundation                      0x33a63fc7 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:] + 18
9   CoreFoundation                      0x33a6cd51 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 388
10  UIKit                               0x3224b577 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 586
11  UIKit                               0x3224cb39 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 92
12  UIKit                               0x3209e871 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 96
13  UIKit                               0x3209a1fd -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 180
14  UIKit                               0x3206648b -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1114
15  UIKit                               0x32065ec9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 44
16  UIKit                               0x32065907 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
17  GraphicsServices                    0x33b0ef03 PurpleEventCallback + 666
18  CoreFoundation                      0x33a556ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
19  CoreFoundation                      0x33a556c3 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
20  CoreFoundation                      0x33a47f7d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
21  CoreFoundation                      0x33a47c87 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
22  CoreFoundation                      0x33a47b8f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
23  UIKit                               0x32099309 -[UIApplication _run] + 380
24  UIKit                               0x32096e93 UIApplicationMain + 670
25  TestP                               0x00002213 main + 98
26  TestP                               0x000021ac start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Where in your code is this exception being thrown? Do you have a breakpoint set in objc_exception_throw?

Comment: sorry, but where i set breakpoint in objc_exception_throw ?? i'm very noob

Comment: [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQn5jU_RHJs) has a tutorial on how to set that breakpoint.  It is immensely handy and I would recommend doing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something went wrong when in xcode 4 with some reference , cause i declared IBOutlet that reference authView then run and it worked!, then i removed the IBOutlet declaration and worked well

Comment: I think the problem is when you have a connection and then you change the variable name while in the view's class files and reconnect the variables with their controls. The old connections are still referenced in the connections inspector for that view in StoryBoard (or you nib file). So you have to remove those connections in the connection inspector. More details can be found in my answer... :)

Answer (score 16):

You've probably got your File's Owner stuff messed up in your xibs.  This exception is getting thrown during nib unarchiving (as evidenced by `+[UINib...]` in the backtrace).  It's attempting to hook up your `IBOutlets` that you defined.

One of your views is set up to be the `authView` of the the File's Owner.  However, when it's time to unarchive the nib, the owner doesn't have an `authView` property, so the unarchiving is failing.

Comment: i searched in all xib for authView reference and doesn't exist, any other suggest ?

Comment: @Robert Bed well, you can figure out *which* xib is failing to unarchive and start by looking in there.  (Though since the backtrace includes a reference to `_loadMainNibFile`, it's probably your MainWindow.xib file)

Comment: I am too late, I guess same issue is there.

Comment: i also delete the MainWindow.xib and still the same error , i looked for all xib and get the same error...

Comment: Check your `connections inspector` tab for the view that's throwing the error. You likely have some outlets listed there with exclamation points.  Remove these and all should work.  I think the problem is just the variable names were changed and reconnected.  However the nib/storyboard file connections for the old variable names still exist.

Answer (score 11):

@Dave DeLong pointed out right.

**Workaround**

- Find when the exception thrown, which viewController is being loaded.
- Then check the nib file of the viewController, there must be an `IBOutlet` attached in xib but might be missed in the viewController.h file or might be some control which was attached is missing in xib file.

**Why running in Simulator?** Sometimes it ends in messing up.

Just do the steps

1. Build -> Clean
2. Build -> Clean All Targets

Now it runs the real code, may be issue got resolve on device also or may be it start throwing exception on simulator also in case if there is really an issue. (I already have mentioned workaround)

Comment: build -> Clean, solved the issue for me.

Comment: build -> Clean, worked for me too. very strange

Comment: For me it started working on device and it is throwing an exception in simulator now

Comment: I had to delete the app from the simulator and only then the IBOutlet connection was lost

Answer (score 6):

This is how I solved this problem.  I went into my 'Story Board' file and selected the view that was causing the problems.  I then clicked on the `Connections Inspector` tab and you will see connection(s) with exclamation points to the right instead of solid circles. Remove these and make adjustments if necessary. Save>Run your app and should work. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

I think that one possible cause for raising that exception is when you have changed the name of some IBOutlet variable after the storyboard connections are already done. Thus the UI element in the storyboard is still referencing to the old variable name. I solved this for me by checking the XML representation of the storyboard (Right click on your .storyboard file and open it as Source Code) and deleting the old (unneeded) IBOutlet variable name.

For example let say you have one UITextField on the storyboard and have the corresponding property for it:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UItextField *myTextField;
```

You connect the UI element in the storyboard to that property and then you decide to rename somehow the variable. Now if you right click on your UITextField in the storyboard, you will notice that there exists two referencing outlets - the old one and the new one. You can delete the old one by clicking 'x' sign in the Connections Inspector or by editing the XML variant of the storyboard file.

Answer (score 3):

I just cleaned the project and deleted the app from the device and it worked again. Error was referencing a view that i had already removed.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably created an IBOutlet, then deleted it, then linked a new one, but in the xib 'Inspector' you forgot to delete the link and now have a duplicate IBOutlet ref that the compiler cannot find.

Answer (score 2):

i have found these errors arise mostly when you connect properties, edit them, and connect them again..  analyse your connection inspector for unexpected values, that remain from your previously created and destroyed connection.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was even more spooky. I had a XIB associated to the VC that I had removed completely as went for code-only. Run on Simulator nicely but would crash on Device systematically.

So I clean, rebuild, closed XCode, went for a snack and shout at the mac. Nothing, the compiler kept pointing to an inexistent button on an inexistent XIB.

Tried by changing the name of the class and that worked!

Comment: Changing the name of the class and xib file and respective target name in xib worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your Interface Builder did not work properly. 
As suggested before, try by cleaning and rebuild. If it doesn´t work, I´d suggest you to re-create your xib interface. It worked for me in a similar occasion.